# How to make gevent sleep precise?

Tags: gevent

I'm developing a load testing tool with gevent.

I create a testing script like the following

```py
while True:
    # send http request
    response = client.sendAndRecv()

    gevent.sleep(0.001)
```

The send/receive action completed very quick, like 0.1ms

So the expected rate should be close to 1000 per second.

But actually I got it like about 500 per second on both Ubuntu and Windows platform.

Most likely the gevent sleep is not accuate.

Gevent use libuv or libev for internal loop. And I got the following description about how libuv handle poll timeout from [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html)

```
If the loop was run with the UV_RUN_NOWAIT flag, the timeout is 0.
If the loop is going to be stopped (uv_stop() was called), the timeout is 0.
If there are no active handles or requests, the timeout is 0.
If there are any idle handles active, the timeout is 0.
If there are any handles pending to be closed, the timeout is 0.
If none of the above cases matches, the timeout of the closest timer is taken, or if there are no active timers, infinity.
```

It seems when we have gevent sleep , actually it will setup a timer, and libuv loop use the timeout of the closest timer.

I really doubt that is the root cause : the OS system select timeout is not precise !!

I noticed libuv loop could run with  UV_RUN_NOWAIT mode, and it will make loop timeout 0.  That is no sleeping if no iOS event.

It may cause the load of one CPU core to 100%, but it is acceptable to me.

So I modify the function run of gevent code hub.py, as the following

```py
loop.run(nowait=True)
```

But when I run the tool， I got the complain 'This operation would block forever', like the following

```
    gevent.sleep(0.001)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\gevent\hub.py", line 159, in sleep
    hub.wait(t)
  File "src\gevent\_hub_primitives.py", line 46, in gevent.__hub_primitives.WaitOperationsGreenlet.wait
  File "src\gevent\_hub_primitives.py", line 55, in gevent.__hub_primitives.WaitOperationsGreenlet.wait
  File "src\gevent\_waiter.py", line 151, in gevent.__waiter.Waiter.get
  File "src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py", line 60, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py", line 60, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py", line 64, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop.switch
  File "src\gevent\__greenlet_primitives.pxd", line 35, in gevent.__greenlet_primitives._greenlet_switch
gevent.exceptions.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I finally found the trick.

if libuv loop run mode is not UV_RUN_DEFAULT, gevent will do some checking and if libuv loop is 'nowait' mode, It will say "This operation would block forever".

That's wired, actually it will not  blcok forever.

Anyway, I just modify the line 473 of the file libuv/loop.py as the following

```py
        if mode == libuv.UV_RUN_DEFAULT:
            while self._ptr and self._ptr.data:

                self._run_callbacks()
                self._prepare_ran_callbacks = False

                # here, change from UV_RUN_ONCE to UV_RUN_NOWAIT
                ran_status = libuv.uv_run(self._ptr, libuv.UV_RUN_NOWAIT)
```

After that, run the load tool, Wow..... exactly as what I expected, TPS is very close to what I set, but one core load is 100%.

That totally acceptable, because it is load testing tool.

So if we have real time OS kenel, we don't bother to do that.